# EC2 instance filtering ports despite same security group

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, tcp, ports, amazon-vpc

I have a similar issue to a previous thread [ec2-vpc-instance-ports-are-filtered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32609501/ec2-vpc-instance-ports-are-filtered) where I'm reasonably confident I have the security group set up correctly and have services listening on the ports, but I'm still seeing filtered ports when running nmap.

I have two EC2 instances.  One is AWS which is working fine and the other is Redhat which isn't.  I have the below security policy applied to both instances. The redhat instance only allows ping and ssh, the AWS allows all rules.

```
Type    Protocol    Port Range  Source

HTTP    TCP 80  212.250.191.71/32
HTTP    TCP 80  85.91.28.28/32
SSH TCP 22  212.250.191.71/32
SSH TCP 22  5.80.62.149/32
SSH TCP 22  85.91.28.28/32
Custom TCP Rule TCP 8080 - 8089 212.250.191.71/32
Custom TCP Rule TCP 2001    212.250.191.71/32
HTTPS   TCP 443 212.250.191.71/32
HTTPS   TCP 443 85.91.28.28/32
Custom ICMP Rule - IPv4 Echo Request    N/A 212.250.191.71/32
```

**nmap -sTU -O** shows

```
AWS version
Host is up (0.023s latency).
Not shown: 1000 open|filtered ports, 997 filtered ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
2001/tcp open  dc
8080/tcp open  http-proxy

Redhat
Host is up (0.024s latency).
Not shown: 1000 open|filtered ports, 999 filtered ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh
```

netstat -plunta | grep LISTEN

```
AWS version

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3020                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      4869/q
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:40781               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      4618/q
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3022                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      4875/q
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      3152/rpcbind
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      4994/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3024                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      4938/q
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:18001             0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      4994/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2001                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      4611/q
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3026                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      4736/q
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2002                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      4621/q
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3028                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      4812/q
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3030                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      4859/q
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      3355/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3065                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      4738/q
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      3706/sendmail
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6010              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      21880/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3034                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      4705/q
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3067                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      4805/q
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3004                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      5013/q
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3036                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      4932/q
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:45053               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      3173/rpc.statd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3006                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      4979/q
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3038                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      4871/q
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:45375             0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      4994/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3040                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      4742/q
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3042                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      4851/q
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8005              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      4994/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3013                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      4934/q
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1254                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      4994/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3046                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      4857/q
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3016                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      4968/q
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3048                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      4744/q
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:17001             0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      4994/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8009                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      4994/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3050                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      4867/q
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3018                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      4796/q
tcp        0      0 172.31.37.100:17003         0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      4994/java
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:43339             0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      4994/java
tcp        0      0 :::53805                    :::*                        LISTEN      3173/rpc.statd
tcp        0      0 :::111                      :::*                        LISTEN      3152/rpcbind
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      3355/sshd
tcp        0      0 ::1:6010                    :::*                        LISTEN      21880/sshd
tcp        0      0 :::3002                     :::*                        LISTEN      4754/java
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:172.31.37.100:12169  :::*                        LISTEN      4640/java
tcp        0      0 :::3306                     :::*                        LISTEN      3658/mysqld

Redhat version

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8011            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18151/java
tcp        0      0 172.31.31.147:17004     0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18151/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3053            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17851/q
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3086            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17899/q
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3023            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18130/q
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3055            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18074/q
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/systemd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3088            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17973/q
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3057            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18091/q
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:40306         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18151/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8082            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18151/java
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:18003         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18151/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3027            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17960/q
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3059            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17903/q
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2003            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17754/q
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2004            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17762/q
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3061            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18010/q
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:37398         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18151/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1076/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3031            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18089/q
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3033            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18020/q
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1042/master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3066            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18013/q
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6010          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      15960/sshd: ec2-use
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6011          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      15992/sshd: cdoyle@
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3005            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18170/q
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3037            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18095/q
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3069            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17905/q
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3071            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18087/q
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3008            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18135/q
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3041            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17897/q
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:40802           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17746/q
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3044            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17980/q
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8007          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18151/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1255            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18151/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3047            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18015/q
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3017            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18076/q
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:17002         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18151/java
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      1/systemd
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1076/sshd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      1042/master
tcp6       0      0 :::3002                 :::*                    LISTEN      17918/java
tcp6       0      0 ::1:6010                :::*                    LISTEN      15960/sshd: ec2-use
tcp6       0      0 ::1:6011                :::*                    LISTEN      15992/sshd: cdoyle@
tcp6       0      0 172.31.31.147:12170     :::*                    LISTEN      17786/java
```

My first thought was that maybe I have iptables running on Redhat but not AWS however running

```
service iptables stop
service ip6tables stop
```

hasn't helped.  Strange to me that the same security group works on one instance but not the other.

My networking experience is fairly limited, so any ideas gratefully appreciated.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Easy test: allow all/all/all in the security group. If that fixes it, your security group settings are in fact not correct.

Answer (score 0):

I would check SELinux to ensure it is properly  configured. If anything, try changing it to not enforce.

https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux

https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/sec-sel-enable-disable-enforcement.html

Comment: Thanks for that Bryce, appreciate it.  I found selinux was running and enforced, and tried it in permissive mode which didn't work.  So I've now edited the /etc/selinux/config and set it to disabled.  Even tried rebooting the system, starting up the relevant processes again and still getting similar results 

# getsebool -a
getsebool:  SELinux is disabled

Answer (score 0):

Fixed - needed to flush the cached rules of iptables with

```
iptables -F
```